# ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set TEST.NOTSORTEDTEST

Tags: sas

[Click to see image of my simple code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSJUf.jpg)

[image]

[Click to see the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju5Yq.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Please post your code and log as text not images. It's easier for users to modify the code you post and point out issues in the log if we can copy and paste it rather than have to type it all out. [ask]

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicated, your data set is not sorted. You need to sort it to have your `BY` statement work.

```
proc sort data=test.notsortedtest;
by name;
run;
```

Then run your code after. The `by` statement in your `sort` should match the `by` in your data step.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions to your problem:
1) sort
2) index

Can you see in the exmaple code:

```
    /*example table is not sorted*/
    data test;
    id=1;a='aaa';output;
    id=2;a='aaa';output;
    id=1;a='aaa';output;
    run;

    /*sort for by*/
    proc sort data=test;
    by id;
    run;

    /*read by by*/
    data test2;
     set test;
     by id;
    run;

    /* expmaple 2 table is not sorted but have index by by variable*/

    data test(index=(id));
    id=1;a='aaa';output;
    id=2;a='aaa';output;
    id=1;a='aaa';output;
    run;

    /* not neccessary the sort if you have index */

    data test2;
     set test;
     by id;
    run;
```